# Capturing VHS tapes

Tags: video, synchronization

I bought a [Video-2-PC DIY Video Capture Kit](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Video-2-PC-Capture-Windows-Camcorder-Transfer/dp/B0049BE3TA/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1427295715&sr=8-5&keywords=vhs%20converter) which includes a copy of ArcSoft Showbiz 3.5, which I found to be too restrictive and low quality, and VirtualDub 1.9.11.0, which I eventually got to grips with and started using after many viewings of the included tutorial.

However, the longer the capture the more the video and audio are out of sync and I have not been able to resolve this.

Can anyone recommend some software that can capture, deinterlace, and compress video from an input source (a VHS player, in my case) while accounting for and correcting blemishes (audio sync problems, in my case)?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can capture the video and audio separately. Then, when both parts are captured, combine them together.

I believe if you have a capture card running through linux, you can pipe the input through your video capture software. Same thing goes for the audio.